# wildfly quickstart microprofile-health : NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, java-ee-8, microprofile

I use wildfly-25.0.1.Final. I can't test the microprofile-health quickstart :

```
Failed to define class org.wildfly.quickstarts.microprofile.health.DatabaseConnectionHealthCheck in Module "deployment.microprofile-health.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/wildfly/quickstarts/microprofile/health/DatabaseConnectionHealthCheck (Module "deployment.microprofile-health.war" from Service Module Loader): org/eclipse/microprofile/health/HealthCheck
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1095)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:753)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at org.jboss.as.weld@25.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.WeldModuleResourceLoader.classForName(WeldModuleResourceLoader.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AnnotatedTypeLoader.loadClass(AnnotatedTypeLoader.java:83)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AnnotatedTypeLoader.loadAnnotatedType(AnnotatedTypeLoader.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.FastAnnotatedTypeLoader.loadAnnotatedType(FastAnnotatedTypeLoader.java:108)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:87)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$1.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:55)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$1.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
```

But the problem disappears if I start wildfly with standalone-microprofile.xml. Unfortunately, the quickstart doesn't say so.

So it looks like the microprofile.health-smallrye has disappeared in wildfly-25.0.1 standalone.xml (it was there in wildfly-20.0.1).

My question is : how to add the microprofile.health-smallrye to an existing standalone.xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there was a [bug](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-14927) filed for this, but it was fixed in WildFly 25. That said I do not see the reference in the default README.

That said it does require the `standalone-microprofile.xml`. You can also add the subsystem with CLI to `standalone.xml` and runt it that way as well. The following CLI commands will add the `microprofile-health-smallrye` to any configuration you start with that does not already include the subsystem.

```
/extension=org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.health-smallrye:add
/subsystem=microprofile-health-smallrye:add
```